# Got fatal error in PHP array

Tags: php, algorithm, data-structures

```
$all = array($stu_quiz_1, $stu_quiz_2, $stu_quiz_3);

$length = count($all);

$low = 10;

$lowest = 0;

for($i = 0; $i<$length; $i++){

if($all($i)<= $low){ // line 34

    $lowest = all($i);

}
else{
    continue;
}
return $lowest;
}
```

I am new at php so please help me to find it. I just want to get lowest value from this  code. I have three values like `$stu_quiz_1 = 20`, and so on ...it shows:

> Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\install\htdocs\just\quiz_handle.php on line 34

Comment: Is `$all` a function ?

Comment: $all  is a array that contain 3 values like 10, 20, 30 Daan

Comment: if you simply want to get the lowest value in the array why not use `$lowest=min( $all );` or `$highest=max( $all );`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To simply get highest or lowest values from an array there are some perfectly suited functions built into the core of PHP - namely `max` and `min`.

```
$all=array( 0,1,23,99,34,838 );

$lowest = min( $all );
$highest= max( $all );

echo $lowest,', ', $highest;
/* output: 0, 838 */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($all($i)<= $low){ // line 34
```

`$all` is not a function so you can't use parentheses. You'll have to use square brackets `[]` to access the array value.

Answer (score 0):

Man... it is not `$all($i)`, but `$all[$i]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your function is called `all` then your `if` clause should be called like below

```
if(all($i)<= $low){ // line 34
```

Note the missing `$` from the beginning, thus the name is a `string` and not a variable.

Comment: but now prob is i don't get the lowest value i got  lowest  value which 0 ... which is not currect.. please help ..

Comment: please edit your question with the full function definition, give some sample values and the expected result

Answer (score 0):

This line :

```
$lowest = all($i);
```

Means that you're calling the function all() with $i as a parameter.

But you $all is actually an array not a function so to access an element of an array you use `[]`.

So you have to change it to :

```
$lowest = $all[$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

First:
Change `$all($i)` to `$all[$i]` (on line 34)

Second: Change `$lowest = all($i);` (below the line 34) with `$lowest = $all[$i];`. In this you were missing a `$` sign in front of `all` and `$i` was to be kept inside `[]` because `$all` is a variable (containing an array).